# With Basic authentication deprecated, how to create a JIRA ticket using REST API in R (or using POSTMAN REST client)?

Tags: r, postman, jira-rest-api

There are different methods of authentication listed [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/security-overview/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819786/using-jira-rest-api). However, when I tried each of them, I get that method has been deprecated. For example, when I try the basic method of authentication to access a project in Jira work management like as given in the help documentation,

```
curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta
```

I get the following error message. Can someone direct me to a working example?

```
Basic authentication with passwords is deprecated.  For more information, see: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-with-passwords-for-jira-and-confluence-apis-972355348.html
```

Comment: What is your JIRA Version? Because, I didn't get the deprecated warning after using the Basic Auth.

Comment: Whatever is the recent version.

Comment: I am now able to authenticate using curl with base64(userid:password)  Bearer authorization. However, I am not able to create Tasks, etc., through REST API using R or POSTMAN REST client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular [basic authentication with password is deprecated](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/deprecation-notice-basic-auth/). You need to replace the password with a [token](https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/) instead and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a token by following this instruction https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/

After the token is generated, you need to copy it. You can test it at Postman using Basic Auth with username as your email and password as the token.

[image]